# All my apps crashing on launch on physical iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I was working on a new app but when I tried it on a real device it crashed with a message of

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CFAlertViewController.framework/CFAlertViewController

[image]

So, I tried to clean the build, clean project and delete DerivedData, but still crashing with the same message.
I decided to uninstall CFAlertViewController pod and tried again to run the app and it crashed again with no message.

[image]

in the end, I removed all pods and the app working successfully on my iPhone.

I tried all my previous apps that contain **Cocoa pods** but they all crashing on a real device.

I searched a lot for a solution but nothing works for me.

I'm using:

1. Xcode 11.3.1
2. iOS 13.3.1
3. Cocoapods 1.8.4

Comment: Do you have a free or paid developer membership?

Comment: @Paulw11 free membership

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `podfile` comment the `use_framework!` line and run your pod install again.
It is a problem in iOS 13.3.1 with dynamic frameworks